# Call start method two times

Tags: java, multithreading

Why does the following code throws an Exception?

```
class MyThread extends Thread 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        t.start();
        System.out.print("one. ");
        t.start();
        System.out.print("two. ");
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.print("Thread ");
    }
}
```

Could you point me out to the `JLS`?

Comment: Lazy question.  Read the javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

That's the contract of the [start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) method :

```
public void start()

Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Throws:
    IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.
```

You can't start a thread twice.

Answer (score 1):

As other responses say, you can't start a Thread twice. However, maybe what you want to do is to start 2 threads: in this case, just instanciate again your thread object:

```
    MyThread t = new MyThread();
    t.start();
    System.out.print("one. ");
    MyThread t2 = new MyThread();
    t2.start();
    System.out.print("two. ");
```